# Create video thumbnail with OS X from command line

Tags: macos, command-line

How can I create a thumbnail from a photo or a video with the standard OS X tools? I mean, Finder is able to do it, so (being a Linux user), I expect to be able to do exactly the same without the GUI; is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's *far* from perfect however you can use the save the thumbnail that Quick Look generates in the Finder by running the following command:

```
qlmanage -ti /PATH/TO/VIDEO_FILE.ext -o /PATH/TO/SAVE/PNG/TO
```

By default this produces a 128x128 png. Removing the `i` in the `-ti` will give you a PNG with the same aspect ratio as the video with the longest side being 128px.

To make it larger add the `-s` option or the `-f` option:

```
#512px version of the Finder icon
qlmanage -ti /PATH/TO/VIDEO_FILE.ext -s 512 -o /PATH/TO/SAVE/PNG/TO

#2.0 scaled version aka 256px
qlmanage -ti /PATH/TO/VIDEO_FILE.ext - 2.0 -o /PATH/TO/SAVE/PNG/TO
```

If you want better results (eg. choose your frame) I recommend using MacPorts to install ffmpeg or ImageMagick. (See fideli's answer)

Comment: great, although it's not very conveniant to specify a path and not directly the file name, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Kevin: If you're in the same folder on the command line you don't need to use full paths.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on www.haykranen.nl's post, install ffmpeg and ImageMagick using MacPorts.

For pictures, create a thumbnail using (i.e. fits within 250x90):

```
convert -thumbnail 250x90 in.png out.png
```

More info [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#height).

For movies, create a thumbnail using:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:09:00 in.avi -vcodec png -vframes 1 -an \
-f rawvideo -s 119x64 out.png
```

or

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:09:00 in.avi -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an \
-f rawvideo -s 119x64 out.jpg
```

where `-ss 00:09:00` represents the point you want to take the thumbnail from (i.e. starting time), `-vcodec` represented here for either a PNG or JPEG, and `-s` is for the final size of the thumbnail. More info [here](http://blog.jeffhaynie.us/extract-thumbnail-from-video.html).

Unfortunately, these tools aren't standard OS X tools. Your suggestion about how *Finder is able to do it* likely happens through a QuickTime or CoreVideo method that isn't easily accessible at the command line.

Comment: Quick Look (how Finder does it) is available on the command line :-)

Comment: Ah, learned something new!

Comment: Thanks for this answer as well, it will be useful to get a more powerfull tool! is there anyway to take the screenshot at a random time of the video?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a native command available for that, but you could always try installing ffmpeg from MacPorts, or alternatively (for photos), ImageMagick.